PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User] (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods') error in react-native
I have changed IOS platform 12,4 to 13.0, Run app its show error.
Info:: node: 16.20.2,  react-native: 0.70.7,  Xcode: 15.3
Error:

PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs
/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-gnqotbvmyutbhudgevjoswppaqfs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-23F20C4BE9FBA43E98A4264F59AC8039.sh
(in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')

I try so many changes but this issue not solved!
